# Hyperledger Endorsement Failure when Invoking chaincode - failed: signature set did not satisfy policy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I am using balance transfer application with custom chaincode, when I use endorsement policy `'1-of':[{ 'signed-by': 0 }, { 'signed-by': 1 }]` then every thing works fine however if I use `'2-of':[{ 'signed-by': 0 }, { 'signed-by': 1 }]` invoke transaction fails with below error:

**Fabric Peer Error log:**

> Validate -> ERRO 078 VSCC error: stateBasedValidator.Validate failed,
>   err validation of endorsement policy for chaincode mycc in tx 4:0
>   failed: signature set did not satisfy policy 2019-01-02 07:24:40.782
>   UTC [committer.txvalidator] validateTx -> ERRO 079 VSCCValidateTx for
>   transaction txId =
>   815553b7cabb383f59d4abd3c2bdc3deda5b74169048e3b3b837f46adbd85099
>   returned error: validation of endorsement policy for chaincode mycc in
>   tx 4:0 failed: signature set did not satisfy policy

**Node-SDK logs show the following**

> [2019-01-02 02:24:40.826] [ERROR] invoke-chaincode - The invoke
>   chaincode transaction was invalid, code:ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE
>   [2019-01-02 02:24:40.827] [ERROR] invoke-chaincode - Error: The invoke
>   chaincode transaction was invalid, code:ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE

Any help in resolving this will be very helpful

Comment: Are you submitting request proposals to peers from both of the orgs?  I believe balance transfer only requests endorsement from a peer from one org not from both.

Comment: Hi Gari Singh,

This is how my request looks

Invoke Transaction: 
http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes/mycc \
-H "authorization: Bearer $ORG1_TOKEN" \
-H "content-type: application/json" \
-d '{
"peers": ["peer0.org1.example.com","peer1.org2.example.com"],
"fcn":"invoke",
"operation":"commit",
"args": ["commit","true","a","b","c"]
}')

So essentially i am sending the request to peers of both orgs. I will try with just one org at a time and share the response.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Gari Singh

I tried with sending request to peer of one org but still the same issue. ENDORSEMENT FAILURE

Here is the endorsement policy by default

'endorsement-policy': {
            identities: [
      { role: { name: 'member', mspId: 'Org1MSP' }},
      { role: { name: 'member', mspId: 'Org2MSP' }}
            ],
            policy: {
      '2-of':[{ 'signed-by': 0 }, { 'signed-by': 1 }]
            }
           }

Comment: Hi @GariSingh

I have uploaded my code to github
[link](https://github.com/psanket/balance-transfer-modified)

Comment: Hi @GariSingh

The code that i am using is uploaded here
https://github.com/psanket/balance-transfer-modified

Answer (score 2):

I ran the environment on my own system and determined that it is not an issue with the chaincode, but rather an issue with the invoke requests that is being sent.

So the invoke request being made in testAPI.sh and testInvoke.sh is

```
TRX_ID=$(curl -s -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes/mycc \
  -H "authorization: Bearer $ORG1_TOKEN" \
  -H "content-type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "peers":  **["peer0.org1.example.com","peer1.org1.example.com"]**,
    "fcn":"invoke",
    "operation":"commit",
    "args": ["commitPrivate","uuid3","uuid2-Owner"]
}')
```

What we can see is that the endorsements are being sent to both peers in org 1 and none in org 2. However, the 2-of policy is not saying that it needs 2 signature from any peers in org 1 and org 2, but instead that it needs a signature from a peers in org 1 and org 2.  We can see this from the documentation for endorsement policies, https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endorsement-policies.html#endorsement-policy-syntax.

> Similarly, OutOf(2, 'Org1.member', 'Org2.member') is equivalent to
>   AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')

So if you change your request to

```
TRX_ID=$(curl -s -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes/mycc \
  -H "authorization: Bearer $ORG1_TOKEN" \
  -H "content-type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "peers":  **["peer0.org1.example.com","peer1.org2.example.com"]**,
    "fcn":"invoke",
    "operation":"commit",
    "args": ["commitPrivate","uuid3","uuid2-Owner"]
}')
```

it will work.